# Can't connect to Ubuntu server, gives 'no hostkey alg' error

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my Ubuntu 14.10 server through ssh but whenever I run

```
ssh -p [port] name@hostname.com
```

It simply gives me `no hostkey alg` and drops the connection.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to have the public key for `hostname.com`. Do you have this available? If not there is no way to get this without at least a small bit of human communication (Talking to people is awful huh?). To better understand this you should look at [this page](https://www.vandyke.com/solutions/host_keys/host_keys.pdf)

Comment: Could you tell me the output of `ls ~/.ssh`?

Comment: I have `ssh_host_dsa_key`, `ssh_host_rsa_key`, `ssh_host_dsa_key.pub`, `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` files in `/etc/ssh/` folder, I believe they are the keys you are talking about. @Grammargeek `ls ~/.ssh` command gave nothing

Comment: Try my answer @DarkMind see if that works

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssh refusing connection with message "no hostkey alg"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268272/ssh-refusing-connection-with-message-no-hostkey-alg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server` and then running `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` should fix your problem

Comment: What do I add instead of `known_hosts` ?

Comment: Nothing you leave it the way it is and it must be ~/.ssh

Comment: you can try putting it in `/etc/ssh` but I don't think it will work

Comment: Ok, after I tried it, here is what I got:
`ipsissimus$ echo $(ssh-keyscan -t rsa myhostname.com) >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# myhostname.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
no hostkey alg`

Comment: try then running `echo $(ssh-keyscan -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t rsa myhostname.com) >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: Here is result I have 
`ssh-keyscan: illegal option -- o`
Just to mention, I'm trying all this options on my mac, but I have a root access to the `myhostname.com` as well

Comment: If you have root access then I can give you directions to get the hostkey

Comment: Yes, I do, I have a root access to server, which is on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Are you just using public key authentication?

Comment: Wait! I know on the server you need to copy the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` to your computer in `~/.ssh/`

Comment: Ok, let's try it, BUT, how do I copy it, I have access as root through the console provided by hosting company, and can not connect to server via ssh to download the file, so the question is how do I copy the file from server?

Comment: Just Copy'n'Paste the output of this command to ~/.ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key: `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` @DarkMind

Comment: The problem is that I can't copy anything through the window provided by hosting, and I can't connect to server as root from my Mac as well, because I need ssh for it, is there any other way to copy output of that file @Grammargeek

Comment: Copy the text that comes from the command

Comment: I can't copy it simply because terminal at my hosting provider does not allow me to do it, and I can't login through ssh

Comment: is there any chance to reset ssh? Or maybe I can install something to copy key file?

Comment: How about you generate a keypair on your pc, put it on dropbox, and then download it (using wget) to the server!

Comment: Who is your host?

Comment: Ok, I've managed to install mail client and I'm sending all needed files from terminal directly to my e-mail, do I have to copy only ssh_host_rsa_key or all of them?

Comment: ssh_host_rsa_key, ssh_host_rsa_key.pub, ssh_host_dsa_key, ssh_host_dsa_key.pub just to be sure

Comment: Done, but still same problem `no hostkey alg` have copied those 4 into ~/.ssh/

Comment: What host are you using? @DarkMind

Comment: It's timeweb, http://timeweb.com/de/

Comment: Ok try looking for a control panel of sorts with an option (usually called SSH Keys/Public Keys/Private Keys etc.)

Comment: Looks like can't find any, is there any chance to reinstall ssh and rewrite all previous profiles?

Comment: I think I've got it! do this "To connect by SSH / SFTP using SSH-client, you must use the following parameters:

     Host: imya_servera.timeweb.de (or ip address of the server)
     Username and password from both the control panel account
     Port: standard (22)"  --Timeweb.com

Comment: But if that doesn't work try running `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server` and then running `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Comment: We should have done it from the begging, reinstalling of ssh WORKED, thanks a lot, without a doubt, this is a wonderful evening, thanks a lot

Comment: Haha! That's great! I'll update my answer :P

Comment: if you are somewhere around UK, let me know, it would be a pleasure for me to shake your hand, fantastic help, thanks for not giving it up

Comment: Hahah, thanks a lot for your help 'not even 13 years old' grammargeek, have a good day

Comment: They have to know it, lol

Comment: Nope they don't they have some time in January (maybe the 1st?) regardless this is off topic and we should probably stop :p